# Oracle Forms Master/Detail showing too many children when underscores in parent key

Tags: oracle, forms, relationship

Have a form with a defined Master-Detail relationship between Parent and child tables... fairly typical I think.  However, when displaying the child rows for a given parent, say Parent_Key = "A_C" for example, the form will display not only the children of "A_C", but also children of "ABC", "AQC", and any other "A?C" children that exist.  Oracle is treating the underscore in the parent key like a wildcard, and showing too many children. This has to be something in our settings, there's no way this is what would be normally desired, yes?  Suggestions? I didn't realize it was doing this and now see it's doing it on several forms, not a 1-off fluke... Thanks

using Oracle 10g

Comment: Underscore (`_`) is a wildcard that matches any single character when you use the `LIKE` operator, but not `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I am aware that an underscore is a single character wildcard.  The question is why would a master-detail block relationship (with a join condition using "=") treat the returned detail rows as if it was the LIKE condition between the master and the detail block?

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle support (Doc ID 1018370.6) this is not a bug but expected behavior, but this looks like a bug to me...

As workaround I added a where condition on the detail block with something like this:
 :DETAIL_BLOCK.PARENT_KEY = :MASTER_BLOCK.KEY